# Java - what is called again: <String> <>

Tags: java, generics

What are these called?

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>(sectionIDs);
```

( the part that is <> )

I know it's a newer java feature, I just cant think of the name.

Comment: its a list containing data type string, you can find more about generics in the links provided to you above "the part that is <>" its the part where you tell which data you want to be inside that list

Comment: The funny thing is, Java 5 is more than 5 years old, and to many people (myself included) generics still seem like a "newer" feature...

Comment: @Eli: That's because we're getting old. Anything invented since 1980 is "new".

Comment: I think this question has been posted once per day for the past week

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are type parameters for [generic classes.](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is called [Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html)

Answer (score 2):

Java [Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Generic classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), it exists already in C++ (if you didn't know).

Comment: or rather, something that quacks like a generic :)

Answer (score 0):

They are java generics

Answer (score 0):

Huh, I was going to say, "Those are letters and punctuation symbols. Can you make your question a little more specific?" But apparently a bunch of you figured out what it was he was looking for.